# Upgrading To 4.1.26 From <= 4.1.25 Laravel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have followed the instructions on Laravel's upgrade page, by firstly adding the nullable TEXT column into the user's table (within my migration file), labelled `remember_token`. I then add the three functions into the user's model.

When I run `composer update`, it brings up an abstract class error - referencing the user's model, within any page I visit. Why is this? Have I followed the instructions incorrectly?

I need to run `composer update` to remove another plugin, but it will update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prefix` was a `faker` reference that it was trying to find, but it doesn't exist. Removing this allowed the database seeding to correctly work.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the column you have added is not nullable? In my case, my migration file looked like:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
});
```

and I've added this:

```
public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

to my Users model and everything works great.

Comment: I follow your instructions, and then once I run `composer update`, I then have to `migrate:refresh --seed`, and the error is:   [InvalidArgumentException] Unknown formatter "prefix". However, when I roll back to my previous version before the update, the seeding works correctly.

Comment: Does your seed contain the new `remember_token` column? Maybe this is causing the error.

Comment: That shouldn't matter as the remember_token is nullable? If that's right?

Answer (score 0):

> I then add the three functions into the user's controller.

Not controller, add functions into `models/User.php`

Comment: I apologise, that's what I did. I've amended my text.